# SQLite select query is not working

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need a little help out here , In my application the SQLite SELECT query is not working ..is the syntax correct ? if not can anybody suggest some working syntax..

giving my query below

```
     String selectQuery="select * from  EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_CODE=" + Emp_code;
     Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
```

I have tried

```
    String selectQuery="select * from  EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_CODE LIKE " + Emp_code;
```

but in both cases it does not get any results..

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes around your `employee_code`

```
String selectQuery="select * from  EMPLOYEES 
                    WHERE EMPLOYEE_CODE = '" + Emp_code + "'";
```

Comment: You probably don't want the spaces between `'` and `"`.

Comment: Probably better to give an answer that works. If you want to point them out, put `^` below them.

Comment: Well I have tried this but it does not return anything , I am getting just blank..

Comment: Yeah now it works ... there is no space needed between ' and " ... thanks guys for help ..good day :)